# "page_url" in WATIR when part of it is changing on run time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am working on WATIR using page object. Here we need to make page files in `.rb` example

`order_page.rb`
URL for this page is https://www.test-xyz.com/order/123123 here last digits of this page always changes.

Now how to create a page object for this page file so that I can use:

`on(OrderPage).continue_shopping`

Comment: Can you elaborate on where the problem is? Given the way you want to use the page object, the page URL is irrelevant - ie you could just not define the page object's url.

Comment: `link(:continue_shopping, :text => 'Continue Shopping')` is page object written in class `OrderPage` in `order_page.rb` file. Now I want to use this statement `on(OrderPage).continue_shopping`. When I would be using this this code would first execute `page_url` which cant be `https://www.test-xyz.com/order/xxxxxx` as order number is changing so how to use `on(OrderPage).continue_shopping`. As of now I am not page object I am simply using `@browser.link(:text, 'Continue Shopping')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `page_url` accessor method is only needed if using the PageFactory `visit` method. It is not used when using the `on` method.

Given that you only want to call the `on` method, just drop the `page_url` accessor from the page-object:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'page-object'
include PageObject::PageFactory

class OrderPage
  include PageObject

  link(:continue_shopping, :text => 'Continue Shopping')
end

@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
@browser.goto('path\to\page\test.htm')

on(OrderPage).continue_shopping
```

If you do want to specify the `page_url` so that you can `visit` it, you can specify a dynamic URL that is evaluated by ERB. For example, you would define the page-object as:

```
class OrderPage
  include PageObject
  page_url "https://www.test-xyz.com/order/<%=params[:id]%>"

  link(:continue_shopping, :text => 'Continue Shopping')
end
```

With this page-object, you can still call the `on` method as before:

```
on(OrderPage).continue_shopping
```

This also gives you the ability to directly access the page when know the dynamic portion of the URL:

```
visit OrderPage, :using_params => {:id => '123123'} do |page|
  page.continue_shopping
end
```

There are some more details/tricks for specifying a dynamic URL on my blog post, "[Creating page objects with a dynamic page_url](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/creating-page-objects-with-a-dynamic-page_url/)".

Comment: Nicely written wordpress post, very helpful and easy to put.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the page url when using the page object gem.  It is only relevant if you have to navigate directly to that page.  If you are already on the page then you can just execute your method.

If you do need to navigate to that page, and don't know the url until runtime you can define a method that takes the part of the url that you don't know until runtime and navigates to the page.

```
def navigate_to_order_page(order_number)
  @browser.goto("https://www.test-xyz.com/order/#{order_number}")
end
```

Then just call  that method when you want to go to the page.